# Including custom Yeoman generators in project

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm working on a project with some private repos and have some Yeoman generators (and sub generators) set up locally. How do I include these *as part of* the project without publishing them to `npm`?

I'd ideally like to have a way for me to do this without having to do the whole `npm link` thing so if it was something that could go into the project's `package.json` file that installed the generator locally when running `npm install` it would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a git repo as a dependency (You know, your yeoman generator)

https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies

Comment: That should do the trick. I'll mark it as answered once I've verified that it works :) Thanks so much!